# nginx + php-fastcgi running slowly

Tags: php, nginx

having some trouble with php-fastcgi running slowly. keep getting 504 timeouts. any suggestions? Below are the nginx site config, top output, and error log:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name  example.com

location / {
                root   /var/www/example/htdocs;
                index  index.html index.htm index.php;

                # Joomla SEF section
                if ( !-e $request_filename ) {
                        rewrite (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ /index.php last;
                        break;
                }

        }

location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9002;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

location ~* ^.+\.(js|swf|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
                root /var/www/example/htdocs;
                expires 14d;
        }
}
```

Here is the top command when the server is experiencing slowness:

```
top - 22:52:10 up 207 days, 21:24,  1 user,  load average: 2.25, 2.07, 2.05
Tasks: 126 total,   2 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.3%us, 11.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.6%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 25.8%st
Mem:   1639756k total,  1444380k used,   195376k free,   236768k buffers
Swap:  3145720k total,    18908k used,  3126812k free,   642228k cached

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                             
 702 mysql     20   0  350m  35m 5344 S   69  2.2  38:36.62 mysqld                                                                                               
 6659 www-data  20   0  197m  20m 3764 S   11  1.3   1:14.59 php-cgi                                                                                              
 6658 www-data  20   0  197m  19m 3776 S    7  1.2   1:06.68 php-cgi                                                                                              
 6660 www-data  20   0  199m  20m 4380 S    6  1.3   1:11.56 php-cgi                                                                                              
 6662 www-data  20   0  191m  14m 3732 S    4  0.9   1:08.79 php-cgi                                                                                              
 6661 www-data  20   0  197m  20m 3744 S    3  1.3   1:14.09 php-cgi
```

The nginx log shows a lot of these errors:

```
2011/01/25 09:06:37 [error] 13031#0: *850 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 50.8.71.165, server: example.com, request: "GET /events/item/root/calendar_event HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://www.something.com/calendar.cfm?fuseaction=ViewEventDetails&EventID=304"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is definitely related to the MySQL process being at about 70% CPU usage.  The reason why you're getting errors in PHP/Nginx is that PHP will probably throw an error if the connection to MySQL takes too long.

One suggestion is to tune MySQL performance for this type of usage. A good diagnostic tool is [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html), which can help find bottlenecks in MySQL.

Another (and more simple) solution is to just upgrade the database server (or offload it to a separate server) so MySQL has more memory/disk-resources to work with.